# Sharepoint List JSON formatting to round down to nearest year using floor

Tags: json

I'm trying to get the amount of years that have gone from a purchase date until today.
The "Purchase" column is an input field, and takes date as an input.
[image]

What I'm trying to do is to show the years from purchase date until now in the YearsInUse column, but why does my JSON show me "51" with this code.

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "=floor((Number(@now)-Number([$Purchase]))/(1000*60*60*24*365))"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The title of the Purchaes column was not the same as the name when it was created, so the $Purchase field was never correct.